# addObserver:forKeyPath is crashing the app, KVO, objective c

Tags: objective-c, parallax, objective-c-category, addobserver

I am doing the parallax effect by using category by doing :

```
    add and UIView into the uitableView (via category
    add addObserver:forKeyPath so that whenever tableview is moving, i will reframe the view above
```

Details are below
UIScrollView+Parallax.h

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

    @class ParallaxView;
    @interface UIScrollView (Parallax)

    @property (strong, nonatomic)   ParallaxView    *parallaxView;
    - (void) addParallaxViewWith:(UIView*)parallaxView;
    - (void) removeKVO;

    @end


    @interface ParallaxView : UIView

    @end
```

UIScrollView+Parallax.m

```
static char parallaxKey;
    @implementation UIScrollView (Parallax)
    @dynamic parallaxView;


    #pragma mark - Add parallax view to scrollView
    - (void) addParallaxViewWith:(ParallaxView*)pView {
        if ( !self.parallaxView) {

            [self addSubview:pView];
            [self setParallaxView:pView];
        }

    }

    #pragma mark - Set parallaxView + register parallaxView as an observer
    - (void) setParallaxView:(ParallaxView *)parallaxView {
        objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &parallaxKey, parallaxView, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_ASSIGN);
    /* THESE LINE ARE CRASHING THE APP */
    //    [self addObserver:self.parallaxView
    //           forKeyPath:@"contentOffset"
    //              options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
    //              context:nil];
    }

    #pragma mark - Get parallaxView
    - (ParallaxView*) parallaxView {
        return (objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &parallaxKey));
    }
    #pragma mark - Remove 
    - (void)removeKVO {
            [self removeObserver:self.parallaxView forKeyPath:@"contentOffset"];
    }

    @end

    @implementation ParallaxView

    -(id)init
    {
        //load xib from main bundle and assign it to self
        self = [[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"Parallex"
                                             owner:self
                                           options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];

        return self;
    }

    -(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
    {
        self = [self init];
        [self setFrame:frame];

        return self;
    }

   ................

    @end
```

And I am adding parallax to the table by doing

```
ParallaxView *pView = [[ParallaxView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 160)];

[self.tableView addParallaxViewWith:pView];
```

However, `[self addObserver:forKeyPath:options:context:nil]` keeps crashing the app without no clues at all. If I comments this line out and app is not crashing but parallex effect is not working.

Any ideas for this problematics. Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
@implementation ParallaxView

//Add Observe Method
-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context{
    if([keyPath isEqualToString:@"contentOffset"]){
        NSLog(@"contentOffset:%@", [change objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeNewKey]);
    }
}

@end
```

Try to replace

```
 objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &parallaxKey, parallaxView, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_ASSIGN);
```

with

```
//Change to OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC
objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &parallaxKey, parallaxView, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
```

`parallaxView` should be a strong reference.

Comment: simalone:thanks for your help. Unfortunately, I have just gave it a try and still crashing....

Comment: I have try your code in a new test Project, And it works after edit somewhere, see my edited answer. And my init method just call super not from nib, if still crash, check the nib.

Answer (score 0):

Problem in code

```
 -(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
    {
        self = [self init];
        [self setFrame:frame];

        return self;
    }
```

In above code  self = [self init]; and  [self setFrame:frame]; will go in recursion will give crash
,First fix this I guess it will solve your problem,It should be like this

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}
```

and also loading View from nib using

```
self = [[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"Parallex"
                                             owner:self
                                           options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
```

this code is really a bad idea.
you can refer [THIS](http://eppz.eu/blog/uiview-from-xib/) for this task.
Happy and clean coding...